# threepenny-gui - opening files

Tags: html, haskell, user-interface, localhost, threepenny-gui

Dear Haskell community I have written my first gui application and decided to use
threepenny-gui to do so.

The task is the following search the files in a given folder for matches and provide links to open those files. In addition I made nice parse and render function as the files (mostly) have a special formatting.

But now I have stumbled upon a problem - most browsers prohibit links to local files by `href="file://localhost/home/user/folder/file.pdf"` being opened, for security reasons, which I do understand and find completely sensible.

I tried to use `href="./file.pdf"` when the program and the file are in the same folder, which also doesn't seem to work.

The code of the whole application is available at [github/epsilonhalbe](http://github.com/epsilonhalbe/Skriptenliste), I run it in a folder and access it via a browser at `localhost:100000`

Comment: I can't get the "Scan" button to do anything. You should include some instructions for reproducing a problem. But presumably the correct answer is to make all paths relative to the path you put in `tpStatic` in `main`. And I'm sure you won't be able to go outside of that directory (e.g. to `../something`).

Comment: Oh thank you a very lot Daniel Wagner - please write your comment as an answer so I can accept it! I just had to put the files in the static directory. - The reason why the scan button is not working I guess is that there are no pdf files that it can find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HTTP server provided by threepenny-gui will serve up static content from the directory you specify in `tpStatic`. Put your files in that directory, and make your links' paths be relative to it, and you'll be good to go!

As of `threepenny-gui-0.4.*`, there are also two functions `loadFile` and `loadDirectory` that can be used to serve a local file or directory at an automatically generated URL. This can be useful if the `tpStatic` field is not enough.